# And the best new user of 2021 is

Tags: discussion, new-users, reputation, users

Inspired by [this post on SciFi.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13594/106849), I went through the [yearly reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/483/year/sustainability/2021-01-01) to see who the best new user was each year -- the user with the highest reputation for that year, who was not previously ranked.

Last year's winner is [Sergey Zolotarev](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/9669/sergey-zolotarev), with both the highest rank, and the highest single-year score of any new user since the site was started:

[image: Sergey Zolotarev reputation league ranking]

Congrats!

---

Below is complete data from the site's inception:

| Year | User | Year rank | Year reputation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | [Sergey Zolotarev](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/9669/sergey-zolotarev) | 2 | 1,178 |
| 2020 | [gabt](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/8428/gabt) | 15 | 282 |
| 2019 | [juhist](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/6393/juhist) | 4 | 588 |
| 2018 | [Salt](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/5602/salt) | 4 | 878 |
| 2017 | [Jennifer Rae Pierce](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/4159/jennifer-rae-pierce) | 5 | 487 |
| 2016 | [LShaver](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/3379/lshaver) | 5 | 1,111 |
| 2015 | [Fred](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/2345/fred) | 5 | 901 |
| 2014 | [Kate Gregory](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/1053/kate-gregory) | 8 | 807 |
| 2013 | [410 gone](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/48/410-gone) | 1 | 4,724 |